# What is this bump on my cat's lip?

Tags: cats, skin-condition, identification

I've recently noticed my cat has this bump on her lip. I dont know when it appeared exactly, but it's a few months at most.

It feels very soft and the cat doesnt seem to feel pain when it is touched. It doesnt stop her from eating or drinking either.

[image]

[image]
Update:
The bump hasn't gone away with time, but it hasn't grown either. The cat is doing great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a large pimple or a small abscess, an infection in the skin.

It can be painful or get painful quickly, so I suggest you take your cat to a vet.

The vet will make a small incision to drain it. Your cat will most likely not need any antibiotics after this procedure.
This will be done under local anesthetics, so your cat will not feel any discomfort from this and will stay awake the whole time.

This is what I think it is. It could be other things, too, but a vet will know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a wart-like growth to me. It is called [papillomatosis](https://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/skin/c_ct_papillomatosis). My cat has this and she gets bumps like these every once in a while.

Good news is that the growths are almost always benign. My cat also doesn't seem to experience any pain from them, only mild discomfort depending on the location. However, you should definitely take your cat to the vet to have it removed. If you leave it untreated, it could cause other growths like cysts, abscesses and, in the long run, even tumors.

Also check your cat for more warts. They usually tend to appear around the face and neck, I believe.